# Midi analysis for python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

I've been looking for a python3 module that I can use to print out eg: "note 5" etc at the correct intervals/periods from a midi file.

I have been unsuccessful in finding such a module for python3, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to choose any MIDI parsing Python library, and port it to Python 3.